# What is a word for hero, villain and anti-hero types?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that categorizes hero, villain and anti-hero? I am making a database of comic book characters and wanted to classify them under these, but I'm having trouble coming up with a word other than the generic-sounding "type".

Example:

> "What _____ is Venom in this issue? Is he a hero, villain or
>   anti-hero?"

Comment: how about "what role does Venom play in this issue?"

Comment: That came to mind, and while I like it more than "type" it could potentially be confused with another part of my application that deals with the characters in comic book movies. For example Robert Downey Jr. plays the role of Tony Stark in the Avengers.

Comment: Yeah... A little awkward but leaving it as "What is Venom in this issue" also makes sense technically.

Comment: You may be looking for the term _Protagonist_; it includes heroes and other conspicuous viewpoint characters in stories. In the famous SF novel _Snowcrash_, the author names his viewpoint character _Hiro Protagonist_, aka [The Deliverator](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deliverator.pdf).

Comment: To 'fill in the blank' in your example, you could use: "classification", "literary classification", or "class of character".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Archetype](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archetype)** may be a better fit.

> the original pattern or model of which all things of the same type are representations or copies

See also https://literarydevices.net/archetype/

> Below is the analysis of common archetypes that exist in literature.
>
> ...
>
> Example #1
>   The Hero: He or she is a character who predominantly exhibits goodness and struggles against evil in order to restore harmony and justice to society e.g. Beowulf, Hercules, D’artagnan from “The Three Musketeers” etc.
>
> ...
>
> Example #7
>   The Villain: A character whose main function is to go to any extent to oppose the hero or whom the hero must annihilate in order to bring justice e.g. Shere Khan from Kipling’s “The Jungle Book” stories, Long John Silver from Stevenson’s “Treasure Island”” etc
>
> ...

Comment: I don't think so. An archetype is a special example that sets the standard for  a type of character. There are many villains in literature, but few are archetypes.

Comment: A slight suggestion, add the definition to the answer in case the link ever goes dead.

Comment: deadrat is absolutely correct in that the word doesn't fit semantically: it does not serve as a hypernym for 'hero, villain, anti-hero'. Neither is it idiomatic in 'What _____ is Venom in this issue?' The acceptance of and high upvote given to this answer is not encouraging.

Comment: Eidolon could also be put into that spot. However, I think it too would be a rough fit.

Answer (score 1):

***Character*** works as a hypernym; also, ***persona***.

> > "What ***character/persona*** is Venom in this issue? Is he a hero, villain or anti-hero?"

M-W:

> **[character](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/character)**
> *noun*
> **7 c** :  the personality or part which an actor recreates: *an actress who can create a character convincingly*
>
> **[persona](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persona)**
> *noun*
>
> **3**
> *plural* personae :  a character in a fictional presentation (as a novel or play)

Answer (score -1):

Both **image** and **reputation** seem to fit.

> - [**image**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/image) - "a popular conception (as of a person, institution, or nation) projected especially through the mass media"
> - [**reputation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reputation)   - "overall quality or character as seen or judged by people in general, recognition by other people of some characteristic or ability"